# How to use java bean in ReactJS to handle run time values and events inside the bean?Is it possible?

Tags: java, reactjs

Please let me know if there is anyway of using a java bean inside react js. I wish to handle all the events and valuechange listeners inside the bean.Also the data model to store the values of the components in the JS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point to implementing java beans in React, there is no actual notion of privacy in javascript. Java beans is only a concept for data control within classes, specifically in Java.